# How can I compare Dev, Test, and Prod stages of my SQL Reporting Services report servers?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am responsible for 196 different RDL files in a couple of dozen different folders and sub-folders and there are some key missing functionalities in SSRS that make maintaining report servers kind of a nightmare.

We get caught out all the time with differences between dev, test, and production. The project in visual studio doesn't allow you to deploy folder structures and there seems to be no easy way to compare everything deployed on various report servers.

What if any ways are there to make this a bit more maintainable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options.

First one is to compare your ReportServer databases between your environments.  Specifically the Catalog table which houses your folder structure and reports (which have a type = 2 I believe).

Second is the reporting services scripter too which can be found here:
http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62

This is an awesome tool that allows you to manage all your different environments and script them out for backup/restore and comparing.

Comment: It doesn't say that it does comparing. Comparing is what I really want.

Comment: I have done compares between the Catalog table but it is veeery slow because SSRS serializes the RDL files and stores it in a column there. Also, the parameters are stored as plain text XML in an ntext field which is hard to visualize using row-column based comparison tools. I am using Red Gate Software's tools.

Comment: What Jay is suggesting is that you use the scripting tool to generate the rdl files and scripts for schedules, roles etc and then compare the *scripts*, which you should be able to do with a standard text comparison tool. RedGate tools, though very useful, will not be much help in comparing the *content* of a report server database.

Comment: Fair enough, it's not ideal but it's better than nothing. Thanks to you both.